# Max string length of html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string-length

I have some tweets which are being pulled in on my website, each tweet length is different, but I want to make sure they get displayed on one line all the time.

This is how they should appear:

[image: twitter string length]

However, if the twitter length exceeds so many words it falls on to the next line and messes with the design.

My question here is to give this string or div? (Excuse my poor understanding) a max length? Then possibly if we reach the max string length to add a ellipsis (...) to the end of the string.

The idea in my head is something like if #div > 120 then shorten the string to 120 and add (...). Could someone help me make that happen? Not sure if javascript/jQuery is the way to go here? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use CSS to do that without moving into any computations either in JS or jQuery.

Define a fixed width to the div element where you want to display your tweet and apply css class Ellipsis to that element:

```
.Ellipsis
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Is this supported by firefox yet?

Comment: Whats the browser support for this like?

Comment: Ellipsis in Firefox has always been an issue.

Comment: As far as the release versions of Mozilla, after version 7(released 2011), they support ellipsis. Haven't tested it though. Current release being 21.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use the `substring` method for this.

```
var value = "This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.  This is a very long tweet.";

function truncate(value, length){
   return value.substring(0,300);
}

alert(truncate(value,3000));
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/psHDU/)**

Comment: While this will work, you need to be careful you don't truncate in the middle of a HTML element, otherwise you could screw up the layout of the page completely.

Comment: I've gone with the CSS option. Thanks for the input though Kevin and the insight on the substring method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `slice()` method:

```
var formatted_tweet = long_tweet.slice(0, 120) + "...";
```

Or in `function` form:

```
function trim(str, len) {
    return(str.slice(0, len) + "...");
}

var formatted_tweet = trim(long_tweet, 120);
```